# How to Customize bootstrap carousel using fade in effect

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my html code for carousal

```
  <section id="showcase">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1 active">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block text-right mb-5">
          <h1 class="display-3">Heading One</h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus illum commodi enim consequatur nesciunt voluptatum perspiciatis sint. Nemo, modi nulla.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg">Sign Up Now</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-2">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block mb-5">
          <h1 class="display-3">Heading Two</h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus illum commodi enim consequatur nesciunt voluptatum perspiciatis sint. Nemo, modi nulla.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-3">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-sm-block text-right mb-5">
          <h1 class="display-3">Heading Three</h1>
          <p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Natus illum commodi enim consequatur nesciunt voluptatum perspiciatis sint. Nemo, modi nulla.</p>
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Learn More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" class="carousel-control-prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" class="carousel-control-next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

I want to style fade in effect for this slide. can anyone help me to make my css code.
i found some css code for carousel like this.

but it's not working properly.

```
     .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item {
  -webkit-transition-property: opacity;
  transition-property: opacity;
 }
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .item,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
   opacity: 0;
 }
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next.left,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev.right {
  opacity: 1;
 }
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .next,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .prev,
 .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.left,
  .carousel-fade .carousel-inner .active.right {
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
          transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
 }
 .carousel-fade .carousel-control {
  z-index: 2;
 }
  html,
  body,
 .carousel,
 .carousel-inner,
 .carousel-inner .item 
{
  height: 100%;
  }
 .item:nth-child(1) {
    background: url("../img/img2.jpeg");
   background-size: cover; 
  }
  }
 .item:nth-child(2) {
    background: url("../img/img2.jpeg");
    background-size: cover; 
 }
 }
 .item:nth-child(3) {
   background: url("../img/img2.jpeg");
   background-size: cover; 
  } 
 }
```

i want to edit this css code for my bootstrap carousal.

if anyone know another method for fade in effect please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one. Hope it is helpful to you

```
.carousel .item {
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
opacity:0;
}

.carousel .active.item {
opacity:1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .active.left,
.carousel.carousel-fade .active.right {
left: 0;
z-index: 2;
opacity: 0;
filter: alpha(opacity=0);
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .next,
.carousel.carousel-fade .prev {
left: 0;
z-index: 1;
}

.carousel.carousel-fade .carousel-control {
z-index: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me. Just add this CSS code in your style area.

```
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item {
    transition-property: opacity;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    opacity: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next.left {
    opacity: 1;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .active.left,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .active.right {
    left: 0;
}
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.next,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.right,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.prev,
.carousel-fade .carousel-inner > .item.active.left {
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: In this line, while adding each item <div class="carousel-item carousel-image-1 active"> add the class .item. That is mandatory.